# Что делать при запросе пользователем ip адреса сервера?

Tags: apache, nginx, веб-сервер

- 200 ничего не делать
- 301 редирект на домен
- 400 плохой запрос
- 404 страница не найдена

Comment: Я бы отдавал 400, т.к. не передан заголовок `Host`.

Comment: я обычно делаю переадресацию на основной домен

Comment: @norbornen а с ip/page что возвращаете?

Comment: @Hipster редирект на `"домен"$request_uri`

Comment: @norbornen А нафига переадресация то? Если подумать. Вообще есть такие люди (кроме меня) которые по ip заходят? По-моему правильно 400 отдавать.

Comment: @Roman почему не передан Host? По идее туда будет записан ip

Comment: @Hipster да, вы правы, нормальный клиент передаст ip. Но всё равно 400, т.к. запрошенный хост не соответствует ни одному из размещённых на сервере сайтов. Кстати, есть другой вариант - отдавать по ip какую-нибудь диагностическую страницу.

Comment: Я у себя отдаю страницу «ну и зачем вы открыли сайт по айпишнику?»

Comment: Что интересно, эта страница почему-то проиндексирована в гугле)

Comment: Ну значит гугл всё таки сканирует ip, просто дублям на ip назначает низкий приоритет. А вашу страничку проиндексировало, т.к. это не дубль, а оригинальный контент.

Comment: потому что я считаю, что у каждого доменного имени должно быть назначение, например: domain.tdl для клиентов, api.domain.tdl для взаимодействия с беком, admin.domain.tdl для бекофиса. при таком подходе лучше избегать дублирования сущностей. в конце концов зачем мне гемор с выяснением "почему эта поделка не работает с при отдаче с ip, но работает с доменного имени"?..

Answer (score 1):

Конечно ничего не делать, отвечать 200, вас ведь, не смущает тот факт, что запрос все равно по сути идёт на ваш IP, через вашу ДНС таблицу? Можно конечно для большей презентабельности перекидывать на домен, но тут вам надо обратить внимание на СЕО оптимизацию.

Comment: SEOшники про это ничего не знают. Поисковикам ip не интересны.

Comment: Если ваш адрес будет биться как Ip сервера, я не уверен что это не повлияет на поисковую выдачу.

Comment: Я в SEO не встречал никаких рекомендаций по поводу ip сервера. Даже гугл на это забивает на своих ресурсах http://216.58.206.3/intl/en_ru/policies/ Т.е. за дублирование контента не считает, а тупо игнорит ip при сканировании.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пользуетесь nginx то [отдавайте 444](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return).

Да, это нестандартный код, но он сразу закрывает соединение, что бережёт ресурсы сервера.

При этом я пользуюсь ansbile-шаблоном default_site.conf.j2:

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}

server {
{% for ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}
    listen {{ ip }}:80 default;
{% endfor %}

    server_name for.trash;

    location / {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

Т.е. по дефолту не слушаем ничего, кроме явно объявленного.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. Я как раз с таким сталкивался и не понимал как меня без ответа сбрасывают.

Comment: Пара улучшений к конфигу: `default` давно уже называется `default_server`; лучше использовать `server_name ""` (чтоб не переделывать конфиг, когда придётся начать обслуживать домен "for.trash"), см. [Имена сервера#Прочие имена](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names); `return` можно указывать без `location`, прямо в `server`.